# Перерисовать jquery ui range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Как динамически изменить min и max в jquery ui ползунке? Мне нужно будет перерисовать элемент

Answer (score 0):

Может быть я не всё понял, но банально так:

```
var minValue = 1;
var maxValue = 1000;
$slide.slider("option", "min", minValue );
$slide.slider("option", "max", maxValue );
```

где `$slide` - это слайдер, полученный по селектору, типа такого:

```
var $slide = $("#my-slider");
```

Данный метод описан в доках: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option. Он устанавливает нужное свойство в нужное значение.